# Facebook Open Graph Action Optional Parameters

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have an open graph action that takes a required reference parameter and an optional reference parameter. My question regards how to define captions for when the optional parameter is not there.
So, if for example, my action is about earning badges that can be linked to a specific event or not as in:

```
[User:Raul] has just [Verb:earned] the [Badge:Gold] badge for the [Event:400 meter dash]
```

But could also be:

```
[User:Raul] has just [Verb:earned] the [Badge:Overall 1st Place] badge
```

Is there any way to accomplish setting the caption to this? How are we supposed to handle optional parameters then?
My experience is that if I set any of the caption lines to include the optional parameter and it is not there then Facebook will use a generic caption for the event.

Comment: No, I gave up long ago, but Facebook has been improving the syntax for actions captions lately, if I where you I would try to look at the latest documentatoin as it might be possible now

Comment: Btw for objects in open graph do you create a new page with metatags for each object. Or use a dynamic one? It's driving me mad.

Comment: I actually have a dynamic page that detects if the request is coming from facebook and only puts the metadata and not the full page to make it faster and avoid timeouts when facebook is scrubbing the data